# Pythonの自作モジュールをfrom importではなくimportだけで出来るようにしたい

Tags: python

Pythonで自作モジュールを作成した際に別のPythonファイルで[from import]という形で読み込む方法はわかるのですが、一発でimportという形にする方法がわかりません。

３個のファイルは同じ階層にあり、test.pyを実行するという形です。
test.pyを実行した際には以下のようなエラーがでます。

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    api = sakanaAPI()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

__init__py

```py
from sakanaAPI import sakanaAPI
```

sakana.py

```py
class sakanaAPI():
    def get_maguro(self):
      return "maguro"
```

test.py

```py
import sakanaAPI

api = sakanaAPI()

text = api.get_maguro()
print(text)
```

Comment: [Python \_\_init\_\_.pyの書き方](https://qiita.com/FN_Programming/items/2dcabc93365a62397afe) の `あ、あと、__init__.py内で関数を定義できます。__init__.pyで定義した関数はモジュール名を書く必要がないです。` を試してみてはどうでしょう？ それからimportするモジュール(フォルダ)の中に実行するスクリプト(アプリケーション)は普通置かないのでは？ そしてこんな記事もあるので参考に。[Pythonでtest.pyを作るな！](https://qiita.com/msmhrt/items/7e2a335a4c64bcc6e044), [Pythonでテストコードとテスト対象のコードを別ディレクトリに分けて置いたときに発生するModuleNotFoundErrorと格闘しました](https://qiita.com/ftnext/items/0fa43030e6a9c28e1338)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[builtins — Built-in objects](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/builtins.html) モジュールを使って、`sakana.sakanaAPI` を `sakanaAPI` という名前でアクセスできる様にする方法も考えられます。
なお、`__SAKANA_SETUP__` を使っているのは多重インポート時に初期化が何度も行われる事を防ぐためです。

**sakana.py**

```py
try:
  __SAKANA_SETUP__
except NameError:
  __SAKANA_SETUP__ = False

if not __SAKANA_SETUP__:
  class sakanaAPI():
    def get_maguro(self):
      return "maguro"

  import builtins
  ## same as `from sakana import sakanaAPI'
  builtins.sakanaAPI = sakanaAPI

__SAKANA_SETUP__ = True
```

**test.py**

```py
pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
  import sakana
  api = sakanaAPI()
  text = api.get_maguro()
  print(text)
```

**実行結果**

```sh
$ python3 -V
python3.8.6

$ ls -1
sakana.py
test.py

$ python3 test.py
maguro
```

Answer (score 0):

次のコードはモジュールsakanaからクラスsakanaAPIをインポートしています。 ※簡単にいうとモジュールはコードが書かれたファイルです、モジュール名はファイル名から.pyを除いたものです。

```
from sakana import sakanaAPI
api = sakanaAPI()
```

次のコードはモジュールsakanaをインポートしていますが、クラスなどのオブジェクトはインポートしていません。

```
import sakana
api = sakanaAPI()
```

このため、`api = sakanaAPI()`はエラーになります。

```
    api = sakanaAPI()
NameError: name 'sakanaAPI' is not defined
```

次のように、クラス名を明示すればエラーは解消します。

```
import sakana
api = sakana.sakanaAPI()
```

#### 回答

インポート文には`import`から始まるものと`from`から始まるものがあり、`import XX`で始まる形式ではクラスをインポートできません。`from XX import yy`の形式でクラスをインポートしてください。

[Documentation » Python 言語リファレンス 7.11. import 文](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/reference/simple_stmts.html?highlight=import#the-import-statement)には次のように書かれています。

> (from 節が無い) 基本の import 文は 2 つのステップで実行されます:
> モジュールを見付け出し、必要であればロードし初期化する
> import 文が表れるスコープのローカル名前空間で名前を定義する。

> from 形式ではもう少し複雑な手順を踏みます:
> from 節で指定されたモジュールを見付け出し、必要であればロードし初期化する;
> import 節で指定されたそれぞれの識別子に対し以下の処理を行う:

---

#### 余談

`__init__.py`はパッケージを作成するときに使用するものなので、モジュールをパッケージとして管理しないときは必要ありません。
※また、Python3.3以降では`__init__.py`は必須でなくなったようです。

Comment: なるほどそもそもimportという形だけでクラスは読み込めないのですね。 そこまでしてやるほどの価値はなさそうですね。
回答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

返信とPython **init**.pyの書き方を参考に記述と、ファイル構成を変えてみました。フォルダーにモジュールをまとめました。
これによりimport sakanaAPIするだけで読み込めるようになりました。

sakanaAPI
-- **init**.py
-- sakana.py
test.py

**init**.py

```py
from sakanaAPI.sakana import *
```

sakana.py

```py
def get_maguro():
 return "maguro"
```

test.py

```py
import sakanaAPI
text = sakanaAPI.get_maguro()
print(text)
```

ただ問題としてPythonのclassを使っていないのでコードとして微妙感がありますが、これで問題ないんでしょうか？